# Why does blending blueberries, milk, banana and vanilla extract cause the mixture to have a yogurty consistency?

Tags: yogurt

- A cup of milk
- A cup of blueberries
- A banana
- Three shakes of vanilla extract liquid

The original plan was to have a milkshake, but the result is quite a nice desert! Like a no cook yogurt.

Looking more closely, the milk has curdled, but not like when mixing it with orange juice. Sort of reminds me of the cheese making process too

[image]

Comment: Is any yogurt a cooked yogurt?

Comment: @tox123 ok, heated, not cooked:-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The pectin from the blueberries jelled in the presence of the calcium in the milk. The texture might be unexpected, but it is perfectly safe and tasty. It is the same process that thickens blueberry jam.

It shouldn't be curdled, that is the clumping of milk proteins in the presence of acid. Here, the milk proteins stay suspended in the milk as usual, it is the pectin that builds the "mesh" of the creamy consistency.

Comment: are there any more well known recipies that combine milk and pectin to make mousse type foods?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Does this always happen when blueberries are blended with milk? Do any of the other ingredients help start this process or help maintain the consistency? Does the ratio of of milk to blueberry make any difference?

Comment: @AntKutschera yes, there are such recipes. I have no idea how "well known" they are, but I have made some of them.

Comment: @JJJ these are interesting additional questions. You could ask them separately. I don't know which conditions are needed, exactly, I have had it happen both on purpose and by accident. I think the ratio of sugar to pectin will be more important.